# draw a circle and with animation transform it to a rectangle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, cocos2d-iphone, geometry

so I have created a circle with draw method :

```
glLineWidth(16);
glColor4ub(0, 255, 0, 255);
drawCircle( ccp(s.width/2,  s.height/2), 100, 0, 10, NO);
```

I would like to know if it is possible to transform this shape to a rectangle shape **with animation** . Thank you . sorry for my english I'm french :/

Comment: Your English is near-perfect. Your code, however, doesn't need backquotes. Just indent it by at least four spaces (or one tab).

Comment: thank you :) but do you have the response ? :)

Comment: You can make it a rectangle by applying Core Animation.

Comment: Core Animation works in cocos2d ?? because I forgot to mention that I was on cocos2d

Comment: I was in search how to calculate bezier for a circle move, and google points here, so if you are in such situation, please look my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20469217/1826679)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For simplicity, I'd use 4 cubic bezier curves - one curve per quadrant of the circle. (This isn't a perfect circle but neither is a 100 segment circle!)  Then, using the `schedule:` functionality provided by cocos2d, I would gradually move each curve's **control points** over time until they line-up vertically or horizontally with the curve's **origin** and **destination**.  This turns the curves into 4 straight lines: a rectangle!

Well, a square to be exact.  You'll also have to move the **origins** and **destinations** of all 4 curves to form a rectangle that is not a square, but you get the idea I hope?

See these links for additional info:

- Bezier Circle math - http://www.cgafaq.info/wiki/Bezier_Circle
- cocos2d - `ccDrawCubicBezier` - http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/2.0.0/_c_c_drawing_primitives_8h.html#a5a391711c0aa611a06167bdd7637571f
- cocos2d - `schedule:` example code - http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/wiki/doku.php/prog_guide:lesson_2._your_first_game#making_things_move

*EDIT: added image*

[image: Bezier Circle]

***d*** = d value calculated from equation at: http://www.cgafaq.info/wiki/Bezier_Circle

***start***, ***control 1***, ***control 2***, and ***end*** are the 4 points needed to make a cubic bezier curve in cocos2d.

Comment: wow it's a little hard to understand like that ;) do you have a code for this, so I could understand better :)

Comment: I do not have any pre-written code for this, sorry. Which part is confusing?

Comment: "I'd use 4 cubic bezier curves - one curve per quadrant of the circle".

Comment: and what about " sing the schedule: functionality provided by cocos2d, I would gradually move each curve's control points over time" how do you do it ? stop the animation ?

Comment: I provided a link to an example of how to use `schedule:` in my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write the code for this.

You could, for example, create a number of control points that are around the circle. Each of these control points could consist of 3 points. Two points that represent two points on the circle and one point that controls the curve of the line drawn between the two points. Now you animate the motion between the control points on the curve such that they move to become the control points on a rectangle and at the same time animate the motion of the third control point so the edge changes from a curve to a straight line.

Comment: yes but i don't know the code for this type of animation that's why I'm asking

Comment: yes but I'm searching for the code that make animate motion between the control point :) I don't know what it is :/

Comment: @gregrock We aren't here to do your work for you. Programming is a lot more than just copying and pasting code chunks - it involves a lot of problem solving too.

Comment: yes but I can start programming if I don't know the code that permit me to do this animation, I have all the rest, I just need this final code . that's all

Comment: So go and work out the code. If you had taken the time to LEARN how cocos2d fits together and works rather than just copying and pasting code snippets then you would understand how to do it. I suggest you go and read some more on cocos2d and stop and think about what you are trying to achieve. Break the problem down into small tasks. I'm not saying this to be nasty - you need to learn what you are doing in order to be able to do more things. This will benefit you and will allow you to grow in your knowledge and abilities.

Comment: Sorry but I can't . I don't find it on internet and I don't succeed to make it . I really need help  please

Comment: @gregrock That's it? Seriously? You're going to spend 3 hours searching some more rather than learning how something works and then give up? And learning how it is working and how you might do it is going to take longer than 3 hours. What you are asking for is far more than a simple answer to a question. If you want to pay, then fine.....

Comment: I've been searching for many days before posting this question, and not only 3 hours Nick . I don't even know if what I'm searching exist . you understand .